# Commutation between Logarithm and Gaussian Integral.

Tags: integration, logarithms

I'm calculating a [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29) (physics) and I arrive to the following expression:
$$\log \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} e^{-nq/2}[2\cosh(\sqrt{q}\,u+m)]^n \qquad(1)$$
My **question** is, is it possible to rewrite this integral like
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} n\log[ e^{-q/2}\cdot2\cosh(\sqrt{q}\,u+m)] \qquad(2)$$
in an exact way or *under some approximations*, in the practice I'll take the limit $n \to 0$.

If the answer is "yes", then under what conditions can I do this?

Comment: The logarithm of a sum is not the sum of logarithms; there is no reason to suppose integrals will do better than sums.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I know, but if you see the expression (2), is not a sum of logarithms because of the Gaussian factor is outside the Log.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen What about under some approximations? In the practice I'll take the limit $n \to 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a simple approximation. Considering $n$ small (analytic continuation), we can write
$$x^n = 1+n\log x+ \mathcal O(n^2)$$

Applying this to the argument of the integral (1) we have

$$I:=\log \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} e^{-nq/2}[2\cosh(\sqrt{q}\,u+m)]^n \approx -\frac{nq}{2}+\log \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} [1+n\log2\cosh(\sqrt{q}\,u+m)]$$
Omitting terms of order $n^2$, or
$$I\approx-\frac{nq}{2}+\log\left(1+n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^{2}/2}\log2\cosh(\sqrt{q}\, u+m)\right) $$

And finally using $\log(1+x)\approx x$, for $x$ small, which is the case because $n$ is small, then

$$I\approx-\frac{nq}{2}+n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^{2}/2}\log2\cosh(\sqrt{q}\, u+m) $$

So in the limit $n\to 0$ we have
$$\lim_{n\to0}\frac{I}{n}=-\frac{q}{2}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^{2}/2}\log2\cosh(\sqrt{q}\, u+m)$$

*Note.* Thanks to @JJacquelin and sorry for not specifying that it was needed an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Eq.(1) and eq.(2) are not equal.

Probably this complicated integral cannot be expressed on a closed form, but on the form of a still complicated series :

[image]

For example :

[image]

Comment: I see. I forgot to ask if 1 ys close to 2 even under an approximation. After the integral I'll take the limit n->0.

Comment: You say $n$->$0$ so, $n$ is not integer ? You should have specified it.

Comment: Yes but there is some technique in this field that works for our proposes. First we consider $n$ as integer but then we take the limit $n \to 0$. Some kind of analytic continuation. So if (1) is approximately equal to (2) I'd be happy!

Comment: I added the explicit solutions in cases $n=0$ , $n=1$ and $n=2$ to my preceeding answer. So you can compare by yourself with your supposed formula (2). I also corrected a wrong coefficient in formula at the end. Bytheway, your formulas (1) and (2) are not consistent in case n=0 : formula (1) gives -ln(2)/2 and formula (2) gives 0.

Comment: You forgot the $1/2$ in the exponential when $n=0$. BTW i already found a solution to my problem. In a moment I'l be posting it. As I said it's an approximation.

Comment: If you are working in a range of around $n=2$, do not expect a good approximate from the formula (2) with $n$->$0$. It should be better to use an approximate with $n$->$2$